# How to design a web app in accordance with Google Chrome's rule of never disabling autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, autocomplete

Apparently Google Chrome simply ignores the HTML attribute `autocomplete="off"`. From what I have heard, this is a design decision by Chrome and not a bug, so this is not very likely to change in the future. Instead, we as developers are asked to design our web app according to this behavior.

I am working on a web app, which displays a table with multiple student names and a form next to the table. Upon clicking on one of the table rows, the form is filled with data about the selected student. When selecting one of the form input-fields, there are so many different suggestions given, since I have filled out this form for each of the students inside my table. This behavior is absolutely horrible. So, I wonder: How would I have to change my app design in order to abide by Chrome's rules and still not have hundreds of suggestions made whenever I select a form field?

Comment: Use a `datalist` to control the suggestions. Autocomplete suggestions still exist, I believe, but they are appear after datalist options.

Comment: @user1599011 thx for the hint! It's an option, I admit it. But I don't really like this solution, since the autocomplete-suggestions still show - the list of suggestions is still awfully long, even longer than before actually.